# how to develop a GUI designer in Jetbrains Rider like in Visual Studio for WinForms, WPF etc?

Tags: c#, rider

Is it posible develop GUI form like visual studio in Jetbrains Rider editor?
 if yes how to set into Rider?

Comment: dont think so. As far as I understand, Rider supports only .net core, which is not applicable for GUI desktop apps

Answer (score 4):

WinForms, WPF, UWP designers are not supported yet in Rider.
But WinForms designer should be available in the nearest future.
Here are the corresponding feature requests:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-16327
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-609
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-1034